# Swift : Different outputs for regular division and vDSP.divide or vDSP_vsdiv

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of floats from an RGB image and i want to divide it by 255. I would like it to be as fast as possible as such I attempted to use vDSP operations. However the outputs are not matching.

I have tried the following:

```
///Image vectors: imageFloatArray1 == imageFloatArray2 == imageFloatArray3
let numSamples = width * height * 3;
var factor : Float = 255.0

var scaledFloats1: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: numSamples)
var scaledFloats2: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: numSamples)
var scaledFloats3: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: numSamples)

//Case 1: Original approach however too slow
scaledFloats1 = imageFloatArray1.map{$0 / factor}

//Case 2: vDSP.divide 
scaledFloats2 = vDSP.divide(imageFloatArray2, factor)

//Case 3: vDSP_vsdiv
vDSP_vsdiv(&imageFloatArray3, 1, &factor, &scaledFloats3, 1, vDSP_Length(numSamples))

/// Output all have same size but case 2 and 3 output values differ from case 1
```

Anyone can explain if this is supposed to happen? And if so are there any faster alternatives to the case 1?

sample output of 10 different values between map and vsdiv:

```
"different values count: " 96892 /// of 196608 values
"map value: 0.23529411852359771728515625000000"
"vsdiv value: 0.23529413342475891113281250000000"
"map value: 0.19215686619281768798828125000000"
"vsdiv value: 0.19215688109397888183593750000000"
"map value: 0.11372549086809158325195312500000"
"vsdiv value: 0.11372549831867218017578125000000"
"map value: 0.24705882370471954345703125000000"
"vsdiv value: 0.24705883860588073730468750000000"
"map value: 0.22745098173618316650390625000000"
"vsdiv value: 0.25490197539329528808593750000000"
"map value: 0.19215686619281768798828125000000"
"vsdiv value: 0.16862745583057403564453125000000"
"map value: 0.22352941334247589111328125000000"
"vsdiv value: 0.22745099663734436035156250000000"
"map value: 0.09411764889955520629882812500000" <- big difference
"vsdiv value: 0.26666668057441711425781250000000" <-
"map value: 0.22745098173618316650390625000000" 
"vsdiv value: 0.19215688109397888183593750000000"
"map value: 0.23529411852359771728515625000000"
"vsdiv value: 0.25490197539329528808593750000000"
```

Comment: Not an answer, but don't you want to **multiply** your floats (which should range from 0.0 to 1.0) by 255, not divide?

Comment: Are the results slightly different, or wildly different?

Comment: @DuncanC my floats currently range between 0-255 and i want to make them range from 0-1. I edited the post to include a sample of some values

Answer (score 0):

The differences you show are too small to worry about. I did some googling, and it looks like Floats have about 6 significant digits of precision. Your answers are different beyond that, in the noise. The differences are likely due to different implementations of the underlying binary math algorithms.

Comment: Some of them are as you said small differences, and I initially thought it would be to some kind of rounding error... However the one i pointed out namely `"map value: 0.09411764889955520629882812500000" / "vsdiv value: 0.26666668057441711425781250000000"` is inside the 6 significant digits you mentioned no?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that one. Yes, that is a big difference. It would be worth logging the dividend and the divisor if the absolute value of the difference is larger than some small value like 0.001. Then use a calculator to figure out the correct answer.

Comment: You are right, I had a wrong index on the output print... I only see variation on the 9th decimal case. Also I did as you suggested and used a calculator with the dividend and divisor and doesnt match either the map or the other operations from the 9th decimal case forward.

Comment: Sure. There is only enough data in Floats to have a meaningful answer to 8 or 9 decimal places at best. The different methods of calculating results may have small differences, but those differences should be down in the "noise" that is beyond the precision of your data. If you want more accurate answers, use doubles. (Those are accurate to ≈14 decimal "significant digits", if memory serves.)